# Ionic3 / Angular2 view render multiple time

Tags: angular, ionic2, lifecycle, ionic3

I created a new ionic 3 project. In my `HomePage`, i have only one varible and one function:

```
count = 0;
printLog() {
    console.log("count", ++this.count);
}
```

In template `home.html` i call this function by interpolation binding:

```
{{printLog()}}
```

It is my whole code. In the console i see the log:
[image]

As we can see the `printLog` function were called 9 times. I can't understand why. Can someone tell me why and how does it work? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please expand on where you put the code. Is printLog() not a method in your component? How is `count` a variable as there is no declaration to this, its just count = 0; Which is broken code. How is the component constructed in relation to the view where printLog() is being called ? So many loose ends for wanting an answer to "How does it work"

Comment: @gerdi: `printLog()` were called in template. I showed it. `count=0` is just a simple declaration in javascript. Contructor is empty.