# Ionic 3 : Why are some functions continuously being called?

Tags: performance, ionic3, angular2-template

I have some utility method calls, that I issue console log messages inside of, whenever the methods are invoked via the template.

I'm attempting to implement a variant of an accordion component.

The screen also has a lot of ion-checkboxes, hierachically listed at various levels (root, cagetories, type within categories), and the components are part of a Reactive Form.

When the details are expanded the methods are getting called repeatedly, despite me performing no subsequent actions whatsoever.

It also seems to degrade the performance of the screen.

**From this information, can anyone surmise what the cause might be?**

Some sort of change detection gone wild?

There is an *ngIf that displays content when things are expanded, then a *ngFor occurs in the expanded list.

It appears to be the nested *ngFor within the *ngIf that is continuously calling out to utilitiy methods.
[image]

The getIndex() method, which appears to be the culprit is being used for two things:

```
 <ion-checkbox [attr.id]="'type' + g + '-' + t"
                            [formControl]=
                          "jobTypes.controls[getIndex(jt, g, t)]"
                            (click)="toggleJobTypeCheck(getIndex(jt, g, t))"
                            class="col3">
 </ion-checkbox>
```

`g` and `t` are `for` loop indices, `jt` is a Job Type, which has an interface structure like so:

```
export interface JobTypeMapping {
    type: string,
    alias?: string,
    num: number,
    name: string,
    group: JobTypeGroup,
    sel:boolean
}
```

Comment: You mean your method is called so many times?

Comment: yes,, I'm wondering if there's a way to do something like let i = getIndex(jt,g,t) inside the *ngFor and reference i instead...

Comment: It happen when you call a function in template. Angular do `doCheck` many times so your function will be called many times. You can check it by add a `console.log` inside `ngDoCheck` function. I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402257/ionic3-angular2-view-render-multiple-time) before and still get no answer.